# Why the word "Com&shy;ment" is rendered as is in Chrome? No soft hyphen

Tags: html, google-chrome, soft-hyphen

I have an html snippet:

```
<label class="col-xs-2 col-lg-2 control-label" for="param_comment">Com&shy;ment</label>
```

and it renders as:

```
Com&shy;ment
```

in Chrome v.29

I expected:

```
Comment
```

What is wrong with the soft hyphen?

## Update:

I meant:

```
<label class="col-xs-2 col-lg-2 control-label" for="param_comment">Com&shy;ment</label>
```

## Update 2:

I think it was an SLIM fault: I had:

```
 = label_tag(:"param_comment", "Com&shy;ment", class: "control-label")
```

now changed to:

```
 = label_tag(:"param_comment", "Com&shy;ment".html_safe, class: "control-label")
```

So the `.html_safe` helps.

But is it possible to do the same without ruby code?

Comment: because it's a special soft hyphenation character, isn't it? I would like to have a word "Comment" splitted when the div is shrinked too much

Comment: Is that an `Unicode` issue??!

Answer (score 0):

The HTML snippet posted contains `Com&amp;shy;ment`, so it works as defined. Use `Com&shy;ment` instead (or enter the soft hyphen as a character, U+00AD: `Com­ment`).

Comment: sorry, I typed wrong - of course I had `&shy;` and still it prints `Com&shy;ment`

Comment: I think it was an SLIM fault: I had: `= label_tag(:"param_comment", "Com&shy;ment", class: "control-label")` now changed to: `= label_tag(:"param_comment", "Com&shy;ment".html_safe, class: "control-label")`. So `.html_safe` helps. Is it possible to do the same without ruby code?

Comment: Then there is something else on the page that munges the content. Check first the HTML document *as received by a browser* (View Source).